# TableView Single cell reload TextField value not getting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing ios app. Data Load on TableViewCell.When single cell reloads from Tableview. After that Enter text on textfield and Getting text from TextField with index. Text not Get.Please help thanks in advance.

Code:

```
     UITextField *atPerRupee = [[UITextField 
         alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2215, 10.0f, 120.0f, 30.0f)];
        atPerRupee.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        atPerRupee.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
        [atPerRupee.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
        atPerRupee.text =   quoteChildObj.atPerRupee;
        atPerRupee.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        atPerRupee.tag = indexPath.row + 40000;
        atPerRupee.enabled = NO;
        [cell addSubview:atPerRupee];

 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview;

        CGPoint buttonPosition = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:_tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

        UITextField *atParPrice = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 40000];
        }
```

Comment: please elaborate and share uitableview delegate and data source code

Comment: Traversing through the subview hierarchy doesn't look the best idea to me as Apple can change view hierarchy of a cell at any time. Rather assign a tag to text field depending on the indexpath.row of the cell which contains it and then fetch the cell using that tag.

Comment: share screenshots of the view and explain what you're trying to do. that way someone can help you better.

Comment: Do you get textfield or not?

Answer (score 0):

you are already getting the reference for textField in delegate method textFieldDidEndEditing
you can get the text in the same like:

```
   -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       NSString *text = textField.text;
       //use the text wherever you want. 
       //if you want to update in array, you will get the index with textField.tag
       NSInteger index = textField.tag;
       //update the entry at index
    }
```